Inline Entity Form (IEF) for Entity Reference Field, Not Using Declared Default Add/Edit Form for Custom Entity
I have custom module that implements a couple new entity types that extend the BaseContentEntity class. One entity is called 'scene_ief' and the other, 'placed_asset_ief'. The Scene entity has a field that is an entity reference field, referencing the Placed Asset entity.
The Placed Asset entity uses a custom form that adds some conditional states to the form fields such that when the 'is_camera', boolean field is checked, the 'media', entity reference field is disabled, and vice-versa.
When the module is installed, and I use the 'Add' form of the Placed Asset, to create a new, stand-alone, Placed Asset entity, the custom form, PlacedAssetForm, is correctly used, and the conditional field state handling works.
However, when I am creating a new Scene entity, and I'm using the inline entity form widget to create a new Placed Asset within the Scene's, 'placed_assets' field, the nested Placed Asset form the IEF uses, is some general form, and not the custom PlacedAssetForm that is specified by the Placed Asset entity.
How can I get the IEF to use my custom form appropriately?
Here is my code that makes up this module and applies some links to the collection and add forms in the admin 'content' menu for testing and illustrating this problem.
ief_issue/ief_issue.info.yml
name: 'IEF Issue'
type: module
description: 'Example illustrating issue with deafult form for custom entity not being used in the IEF widget.'
package: 'Troubleshooting'
core_version_requirement: ^10 || ^11

ief_issue/ief_issue.routing.yml
scene_ief.collection:
  path: '/admin/content/scene_ief'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'scene_ief'
    _title: 'Scene IEF List'
    _menu_link_content_add: TRUE
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer scene ief entities'

scene_ief.add:
  path: '/admin/content/scene_ief/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'scene_ief.add'
    _title: 'Add Scene IEF'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer scene ief entities'

placed_asset_ief.collection:
  path: '/admin/content/placed_asset_ief'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'placed_asset_ief'
    _title: 'Placed Asset IEF List'
    _menu_link_content_add: TRUE
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer placed asset ief entities'

placed_asset_ief.add:
  path: '/admin/content/placed_asset_ief/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'placed_asset_ief.add'
    _title: 'Add Placed Asset IEF'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer placed asset ief entities'


ief_issue/ief_links.menu.yml
scene_ief.admin:
  title: 'Scene IEF'
  description: 'Manage Scene IEF entities'
  route_name: scene_ief.collection
  parent: system.admin_content
  weight: 100
  menu_name: admin

scene_ief.add_admin:
  title: 'Add Scene IEF'
  route_name: scene_ief.add
  parent: scene_ief.admin
  weight: 101
  menu_name: admin

placed_asset_ief.admin:
  title: 'Placed Asset IEF'
  description: 'Manage Placed Asset IEF entities'
  route_name: placed_asset_ief.collection
  parent: system.admin_content
  weight: 102
  menu_name: admin

placed_asset_ief.add_admin:
  title: 'Add Placed Asset IEF'
  route_name: placed_asset_ief.add
  parent: placed_asset_ief.admin
  weight: 103
  menu_name: admin

Scene Entity
ief_issue/src/Entity/SceneIEF.php
<?php

namespace Drupal\ief_issue\Entity;


use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\user\EntityOwnerTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedTrait;

/**
 * Defines the scene_ief entity class.
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "scene_ief",
 *   label = @Translation("Scene_ief"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\Routing\AdminHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "scene_ief",
 *   admin_permission = "administer scene_ief",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "label" = "title",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/content/scene_ief/{scene_ief}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/content/scene_ief/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/content/scene_ief/{scene_ief}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/content/scene_ief/{scene_ief}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/content/scene_ief",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "ief_issue.scene_settings",
 * )
 */
class SceneIEF extends ContentEntityBase {


  use EntityOwnerTrait;
  use EntityPublishedTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

    // Get base fields
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);


    // Label field, for the Title of the scene_ief
    $fields['title'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Scene_ief Title'))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('max_length', 255)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => -5,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        // 'title' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => -5,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ;

    // PlacedAssets field.
    $fields['placed_assets_ief'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Placed Assets IEF'))
      ->setRequired(FALSE)
      ->setCardinality(BaseFieldDefinition::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'placed_asset_ief')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'inline_entity_form_complex',
        'settings' => [
          'form_mode' => 'default',
          'label_singular' => 'Placed Asset IEF',
          'label_plural' => 'Placed Assets IEF',
        ],
        'weight' => 20,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
        'weight' => 20,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    return $fields;
  }

}

Placed Asset Entity
ief_issue/src/Entity/PlacedAssetIEF
<?php

namespace Drupal\ief_issue\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;
use Drupal\user\EntityOwnerTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityPublishedTrait;

/**
 * Defines the placed asset entity class.
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "placed_asset_ief",
 *   label = @Translation("Placed Asset IEF"),
 *   label_collection = @Translation("Placed Asset"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder",
 *     "form" = {
 *       "default" = "Drupal\ief_issue\Form\PlacedAssetForm",
 *       "add" = "Drupal\ief_issue\Form\PlacedAssetForm",
 *       "edit" = "Drupal\ief_issue\Form\PlacedAssetForm",
 *       "delete" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityDeleteForm",
 *     },
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\Routing\AdminHtmlRouteProvider",
 *     },
 *   },
 *   base_table = "placed_assets",
 *   admin_permission = "administer placed_asset_ief",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *     "id" = "id",
 *     "uuid" = "uuid",
 *     "label" = "label",
 *   },
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/content/placed_asset_ief/{placed_asset_ief}",
 *     "add-form" = "/admin/content/placed_asset_ief/add",
 *     "edit-form" = "/admin/content/placed_asset_ief/{placed_asset_ief}/edit",
 *     "delete-form" = "/admin/content/placed_asset_ief/{placed_asset_ief}/delete",
 *     "collection" = "/admin/content/placed_asset_ief",
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "ief_issue.placed_asset_settings",
 * )
 */
class PlacedAssetIEF extends ContentEntityBase {

  use EntityOwnerTrait;
  use EntityPublishedTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {

    // Get base fields
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
    // Can alternatively directly call from ComicsBaseEntity
    // $fields = ComicsBaseEntity::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type)

    // Add the Label field
    $fields['label'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Placed Asset Label'))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('max_length', 255)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'string_textfield',
        'weight' => 20,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'type' => 'string',
        'weight' => 20,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

      // Add the 'is_camera' field
    $fields['is_camera'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
      ->setLabel(t('Is Camera'))
      ->setDefaultValue(FALSE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'boolean_checkbox',
        'weight' => 30,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'weight' => 30,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

    // Add the Media field
    $fields['media'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Media'))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'media')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'settings' => [
          'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
          'size' => 60,
          'placeholder' => '',
        ],
        'weight' => 30,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
        'weight' => 30,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);


    return $fields;

  } // END - baseFieldDefinitions()

} // END - PlacedAsset class


The custom Add/Edit/Default form for Placed Asset
ief_issue/src/Form/PlacedAssetForm
<?php

namespace Drupal\ief_issue\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class PlacedAssetForm extends ContentEntityForm {

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    // Get the entity object
    $entity = $this->getEntity();

    // dump($form_state->getValues());
    // dump($form_state->getFormObject()->getFormId());
    // dump($form['#parents']);


    // Add the conditional field code here
    $form['is_camera'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Is Camera'),
      '#default_value' => $entity->is_camera->value,
      '#states' => [
        'disabled' => [
          ':input[name="media"]' => ['filled' => TRUE],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $form['media'] = [
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#target_type' => 'media',
      '#title' => t('Media'),
      '#default_value' => $entity->media->entity,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="media-field-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#states' => [
        'disabled' => [
          ':input[name="is_camera"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
        ],
      ],
    ];

    return $form;

  } // END - buildForm()


} // END - PlacedAssetForm class


This is the PlacedAssetForm when created stand-alone. We can see it is using the desired custom form, and that the 'media' field is disabled when the 'is_camera' field is checked.


This is the Placed Asset as it looks when it is rendered via an inline entity form inside the placed_assets field of a Scene entity. We see that it is not using the PlacedAssetForm, but some other general entity add form.

